# up for suspension from the commissioner

Tags: idioms

For this particular paragraph:

> [link](https://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/nfl-shutdown-corner/san-francisco-49ers-outside-linebacker-aldon-smith-gets-nine-game-suspension-202308715.html)
>   After the NFL admitted it went too light on Baltimore running back Ray Rice with its punishment, you didn't want to be the next major name ***up for suspension from commissioner Roger Goodell***.

would changing "up for *suspension from* commissioner Roger Goodell" to "up for *punishment from* commissioner Roger Goodell" or "up for *a suspension sentence from* commissioner Roger Goodell" be better?

Comment: "Suspension" used here just means he will be barred from playing for some period of time. There may be a penalty or punishment attached or not, but that is another matter. Also it is not a "sentence", this is usually decided by the judge in a court setting.

Comment: @user3169 So, it is okay to write: "He received ***imprisonment*** from the judge"?

Comment: Not normally, *imprisonment* only describes being in prison, rather than a judge's action. A usage example: "His imprisonment lasted for 6 months."  More likely one would say "He received a *prison sentence* from the judge." or "He *was imprisoned by* the judge."

Answer (score 4):

No.

Each year, many NFL players are punished by the commissioner.  Most of them are not at risk of suspension (for the incident in question).  For example, the commissioner can fine a player.  Here are some actions that can result in fines:

- Intentionally using a very dangerous technique (that is against the rules) while playing.
- "Show-boating":  Celebrating a good play in such an obnoxious way that your opponents will be strongly tempted to use very dangerous techniques against you in the future.
- Never talking to the media.

Here are some actions that can result in fines and/or suspensions:

- Repeatedly failing drug tests.
- Serious trouble with the law.  (For example, drunk driving convictions, "domestic violence" convictions, allegedly aiding or abetting a homicide.)  The commissioner does not follow the same standards as a criminal court.

Thus, "up for punishment from commissioner Roger Goodell" has a different meaning than "up for suspension from commissioner Roger Goodell".

"up for suspension sentence from commissioner Roger Goodell" has two problems.  First, it does not sound natural to my (American) ear.  Second, it sounds like "up for a suspended sentence from commissioner Roger Goodell".  A suspended sentence is a sentence that is not being enforced (unless the punishee does something else worthy of punishment.  It is therefore a "slap on the wrist", not an especially harsh sentence.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for the alternatives you suggest. The most severe punishment which the next major name may receive is *suspension*, and if he receives it it will be imposed by the commissioner.  To say merely *punishment* is too general, since other punishments are relatively trivial; and to call it a *suspension sentence* is needlessly specific, since the term *sentence* adds nothing to the meaning.

Comment: It seems that "to receive ***a XXX suspension**** from the commissioner", where XXX stands for a numerical value denoting the length of suspension like 5-day, two-month, etc...., is more common than "to receive ***suspension*** from the commissioner".

Comment: @meatie Quite so. But if you are speaking of a 'generic' offender, and thus a generic offense, there's no telling what length of suspension would be involved.